# rspec create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Помогите написать тест для action create 
**spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb**

```
  describe '#create' do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

    before { post :create, user: user }

    it { is_expected.to have_http_status :redirect }
  end
```

**app/controller/users_controller.rb**

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      session[:current_user_id] = @user.token
      redirect_to new_user_profile_path
      UserMailer.registration_confirmation(@user).deliver_now
    else
      flash[:error] = 'some have invalid'
      render :new
    end
  end

 private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
```

**LOG**

```
andrey@asus:~/dev/note_work$ rspec spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb 
.....F

Failures:

  1) UsersController#create 
     Failure/Error: params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `permit' for "7":String
     # ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:45:in `user_params'
     # ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:14:in `create'
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:42:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.40948 seconds (files took 18.21 seconds to load)
6 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:45 # UsersController#create
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь лучше `attributes_for` вместо `create`, создав хэш для операции создания пользователя

```
describe '#create' do
  let(:user) { attributes_for(:user) }

    it 'изменяет счетчик' do
      expect do
        post :create, user: new_faq
      end.to change(User, :count).by(1)
    end

  end
end
```

Вы можете опускать FactoryGirl в let-конструкции. Кроме того, хорошо бы привести в вопросе еще содержимое фабрики пользователя.

Comment: спасибо, понял что передавал обьект, когда передал атрибуты все прошло